# SonarQube database user needed for running analysis = security issue?

Tags: database, security, sonarqube, analysis

To run a SonarQube analysis for example with maven, the sonar-database user and password has to be shared and added to maven settings.xml.

So each user has full read-write-access to the sonarqube database? Everyone can manipulate also other tables for ecample to change permissions to projects? Have i misunderstood somethind?

Answer (score 1):

This can be obviously seen as a security issue if you implement a naive installation of your SonarQube infrastructure.

But usually, the good installation is the following one:

- You have a central SonarQube server connected to your DB
- You have a CI software (like Jenkins) that will run the SQ analyses based on the source code located in your SCM repositories

  - The DB crendentials are configured on this/those machines only, on which users don't have access
- The developers run only [local analyses](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Pre-commit+Check) that don't connect to the DB, so they don't have access to the DB crendentials

Comment: Note that you can also use settings encryption to hide the credentials - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369495/how-do-i-hide-sonar-database-credentials-from-end-users/24370391

Comment: Thanks!
Our planned scenario: We have several departments with lots of smaller software projects and usually no CI used (research projects). The teams use different IDEs (also Visual Studio ...). We want to provide the developers an easy way to measure their code quality and also share the reults in sonarqube web gui. Is there another solution to run anylsis secured? Like  Mithfindel suggested?
(Sry for the naive questions. We currently test sonarqube the first time.)

Comment: Using encryption will ensure that nobody will get the DB credentials in clear, so that's the good way to secure the password if you have to install SonarQube like what you said.